# Puzzle Quest 2 weapon and equipment adjectives

Tags: nintendo-ds, puzzle-quest-2

I'm not very advanced in the solo adventure, but I noticed that most weapon and equipment (hat, boots, etc) in Puzzle Quest 2 have adjectives, like *Great* or *Ancient*.

What is their meaning?

Is there a list of those somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each prefix has a unique meaning to it. I *think* I remember reading that there may be some differences in them between the DS and XBLA versions, but I can't find a source for that. The prefix effects vary based on upgrade level (Masterwork, Legendary, Epic) and type of equipment (Accessory, Armor, Chemical, Shield, Weapon).

Here's what each prefix does

```
                                                       Masterwork Legendary  Epic
Prefix       Affects                                        Bonus     Bonus Bonus
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Ancient      Block chance                                     +2%       +5%  +10%
Hell-forged  Double damage chance                             +2%       +5%  +10%
Glyphic      Spell resist chance                              +1%       +2%   +4%
Runic        Double shield chance                             +1%       +2%   +4%
Draconic     Amount of damage blocked                         +1%       +2%   +4%
Daemonic     Matching skull damage bonus                     None       +1%   +2%
```

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/980488-puzzle-quest-2/faqs/60442)

Comment: I did not think to check for a FAQ for the XBLA versions, Thanks!

Comment: Facts are not copyrighteable.